# Adding a new module to IntelliJ Java Maven project somehow makes it stop seeing files in resources folder

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, module

```
Environment: Java 1.8, IntelliJ Community Edition, Maven based project.
```

I've met this odd behaviour when I was trying to create a multi module Spring Boot project and it appeared that the project can not see `application.properties` file that was places inside it's resources directory. The problem isn't in Spring, it can be reproduced on any other Maven project, on various versions of IntelliJ.

After some researching I have figured that **the problem appears when a new module is being added to the project. Instantly after that - without me touching anything else - the file that could be perfectly found and read moments ago, becomes no longer visible for the application.**

One-method project that reads file from classpath and prints it line by line:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Runner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        InputStream resourceAsStream = Runner.class.getClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream("data.properties");

        try (
        InputStreamReader streamReader = 
            new InputStreamReader(resourceAsStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader)) {

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

`data.properties` guts can be anything, I've filled it with

```
number=34
```

So, with no modules added, application works just fine, however after I add one this is the output I get on execution:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

(it cannot find the file hence `resourceAsStream` has `null` value).

- It seems, everything is fine when I use Gradle instead of Maven.
- I got the very same results on my second machine with different versions of IDE and Java.
- In project properties the `resources` directory is still marked as, well, a resource directory.
- Deleting newly created module doesn't seem to help a bit.

So, the question is: Is it about me and my poor knowledge in Maven or in something else that was involved in work OR there is some sort of bug I've encountered? Any fixes / bypasses to be made?

Comment: How are you running your program, and what's the minimal pom change to cause the problem?

Comment: I have reproduced this. Created the issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-290267 Please follow it for updates in YouTrack.

Comment: @tgdavies
I just press little green triangle next to the class name or main method name.
As for the pom file, new module creation changes packaging from jar to pom: 

<packaging>pom</packaging>

Without this line pom.xml cannot contain modules part, yet with it the application cannot see my data.properties file.

Comment: @Andrey so this IS a bug? Unfortunately, YouTrack gives me 404 error when I try to use provided url.

Comment: It looks like a bug. I have filled the issue to investigate it. Sorry, it has been created with restricted visibility for some reason. Now it should be visible, please try again.

Comment: @Andrey thanks a lot, I can see it now.